# Bootstrap navbar-brand centering within navbar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to center a brand image within a `navbar navbar-inverse` in bootstrap. Try as I might with padding, the image insists on sitting on the bottom of the bar instead of the being properly centered. I am using the following code:

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img alt="Brand" src="se-logo.png" height="30px"></a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-brand {
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}
```

Comment: You have to show what you have tried... How are we supposed to help you otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that `.navbar-brand` is a floating element. If you check the styles, it has a `float:left`, so it will position itself at the left of its parent by default. You can fix that by removing the floating property:

```
.navbar-brand {
    float:none;
}
```

The image will still not be centered (vertically or horizontally). To center it, you could update the styles of the container (`.nav-header`) to add a `text-align` (so the image aligns horizontally), and update the value of the `line-height` (so it aligns vertically too):

```
.navbar-header {
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
}
```

You can see it working here (or on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brt8qeLn/)):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
.navbar-header {
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
}

.navbar-brand {
    float:none;
}
</style>


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img alt="Brand" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/30/abstract" height="30px" /></a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

(I used `line-height:50px` because the height of `.navbar` is 50px, but you may want to adapt it to the height of your choice).

Comment: Thanks, great answer.